# Message: Call to undefined function validation_errors()

Tags: php, codeigniter

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined function validation_errors()

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\parking\application\views\login.php

Line Number: 43

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\parking\application\controllers\Auth.php
Line: 59
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\parking\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: <body class="hold-transition login-page">
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('auth'); ?>"><b>Login</b></a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-logo -->
  <div class="login-box-body">
    <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>

    
    <?php     echo validation_errors(); ?>  

    <?php if(!empty($errors)) {
      echo $errors;
    } ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load the validation library either on autoload or in the class where you loading your view If you are using CI2 or CI3 try to this code `$this->load->library('form_validation');`

Comment: Where you loaded the form validation library?

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'form_validation', 'database');


I am used like this ?

Comment: Have you loaded the form helper ?

Comment: Thank you So much, yes i made a mistake in helper form